# Formula / Calculate how much to slow video down to match audio?

Tags: video, video-editor, audio

scenario:

I have video matched with audio (song).

I slow the audio (song) down (eg from 120 bpm to 115bpm ie, I know exactly how much slower the new audio is than the original video)

How do I calculate how much to slow down my video by (in Final Cut I have the option of slowing down from 100% speed right down to 1%) so it matches the slow(er) audio?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(115bpm / 120 bpm) * 100 = 95.83% (approx, to 2 decimal places)

Speed change percentages are always confusing.

[Final cut expresses speed changes as](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12643?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US):

> If you change the speed to 50 percent, your clip becomes twice as long
>   [...] 
>   If you change the speed to 200 percent, the clip becomes half as
>   long

So if you go from 120 bpm to 115 (a slower tempo), you are looking for a longer clip, so your percentage should be lower than 100%.

Comment: That should be `(115bpm / 120 bpm)`

Comment: gah... told you it was confusing :) thanks